# Die Game - max 3 rolls - risk averse utility function

Tags: probability, expected-value

Lets say we have the opportunity to play the die game by rolling it a maximum number of times (we can use 3 for the example), we receive a payoff equal to the number of dots on the top face of the die, and we can opt to stop anytime, with a maximum of 3 attempts.

So if we get a 6 on the first attempt, we would normally stop the game and take the 6$ home.

When we want to find the expected payoff of this game by being risk neutral, we basically determine the expected payoff of 1 roll, then if we get a 3 on the first roll we would roll again, as it would be smaller than the 3.5 of expected payoff, and so on till the 3rd roll, which would lead us to an overall expected payoff of 4 2/3.

But what if we are risk averse, and use a utility function such as log(), how would you solve it and determine the fair value of this same game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u(x) = \log_{2}{x}$ and let $\mathbb{E}_i[u(x)]$ denote the the best value you will obtain in expectation if you have $i$ dice rolls.

Then $\mathbb{E}_1[u(x)] = \frac{1}{6} \sum_{i = 1}^{6}\log_{2}(i) \approx 1.58$

Now, $\mathbb{E}_2[u(x)] = \frac{2}{6} \mathbb{E}_1[u(x)] + \frac{1}{6} \sum_{i = 3}^{6}\log_{2}(i) \approx 1.94$. Here the idea was that if we roll and get number $x$ such that $\log_{2}{x} \leq 1.58 \implies x < 3$, then we should go for a second roll, otherwise just take the first roll.

Lastly, $\mathbb{E}_3[u(x)] = \frac{3}{6} \mathbb{E}_2[u(x)] + \frac{1}{6} \sum_{i = 4}^{6}\log_2{i} \approx 2.12$, by similar logic.

Comment: That is definitely in line with what I was thinking, and it is always good to have a second opinion, which validates our thought. Thanks for reaching out :)